# Access self-installed instance of SQL Server from Azure Virtual Machine

Tags: sql-server, azure, virtual-machine, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

I have created the virtual machine on Azure and installed a free version of the SQL Server database. I have created a new login in the SQL Server to access the database. I also added the inbound rule to enable TCP port on the Azure portal of the virtual machine.

[image]

Now I am trying to access the SQL Server instance from my local computer over IP but it's not connecting. Is there anything I am missing? I am getting this error:

[image]

Comment: Your screenshots do not help, remove them. What is the OS? How is the OS firewall configured? How is the Azure firewall configured? What network interface is SQL Server listening on and the port number? Do not comment, edit your question with details.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why am I getting "Cannot Connect to Server - A network-related or instance-specific error"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060667/why-am-i-getting-cannot-connect-to-server-a-network-related-or-instance-speci)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use [Configuration Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-configuration-manager?view=sql-server-ver15) to enable TCP/IP connections and listen on port 1433.
2. Add a Windows Firewall rule allowing inbound traffic on port 1433.
3. Configure the VM's [Network Security Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/network-security-groups-overview) to allow inbound traffic on port 1433.

Comment: I did everything but I was missing the TCP port in the configuration manager of the SQL server. Thanks, it is fixed.

Comment: Yep.  Developer and Express Edition don't have TCP/IP enabled by default, as they are often installed on developer desktops.